# WireMock request query param is empty

Tags: java, kotlin, wiremock

I am trying to configure wiremock but for some reason the `request.query.state` remain empty. If i change it to `{{now}}` it will insert the current date so the templating is working.

```
upStreamIDPMock.stubFor(
    get(urlPathEqualTo("/oauth/authorize")).willReturn(status(302))
        .withServeEventListener(
            "webhook", webhook()
                .withMethod(RequestMethod.GET)
                .withUrl("http://localhost:8082/oidc/callback?code=$code&state={{request.query.state}}")
        )
)
userService.stubFor(get("/callback").willReturn(ok()))
```

This is my request URL:
`/oauth/authorizescope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8082%2Foidc%2Fcallback&state=UHq4_t4jedo3-gtO2uPqNGemeWf-au9yceyrKVPLN7Y&nonce=FnioULWSy-Hd4mmlC6o15d_BOg49MJlZzi3on7ts_PQ`

This is the response:
`http://localhost:8082/oidc/callback?code=QxyTZeVACxRxzcJmRB4xQciCApy2aNQsbyDg5-sIU7w&state=`

Answer (score 1):

I debugged it and found out that you need to use `originalRequest` in the webhook, i.e. `.withUrl("http://localhost:8082/oidc/callback?code=$code&state={{originalRequest.query.state}}")`

After finding out what the parameter is actually called, I could find a reference in the [documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/webhooks-and-callbacks/#using-data-from-the-original-request) – I now it's done backwards, but I missed it the first time:

> Similarly to response templates the original request data is available, although in this case it is named `originalRequest`.

If you're curious, it's done [here](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wiremock/webhooks/Webhooks.java#L131)